# How to map JPA discriminator value?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I believe I had this working and I must have done something. Hopefully, someone can see the issue right away.

Two classes in an inheritance relationship. Two tables in play. Both tables receive records. Issue at hand: discriminator value not stored.

**Parent Class**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entp", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name="enrg")
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    @Column(name="enid")
    private Long entityId;

    // some string property mapped to column 'nm;
    // some string property mapped to column 'ns;
    // some string property mapped to column 'tmcr;
```

**Child Class**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ws")
@Table(name="ws")
public class Website extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="exdr", length=100)
    private String exportDirectory;
```

**Service call**

```
getEntityManager().persist(website);
```

**SQL**

```
Hibernate: insert into enrg (nm, ns, tmcr) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ws (exdr, enid) values (?, ?)
```

**Hibernate**

```
<persistence-unit name="prod" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>prodDataSource</jta-data-source>

    <class>webadmin.domain.core.Website</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
        <property name = "hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined" value = "false" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

What do I need to do, to have Hibernate include entp column/value in the insert for enrg? In this case, entp value should be 'ws'.

**Solution**

All my mappings/configuration remains, as above. I have upgraded to Hibernate 4.3.6 and under TomEE 1.7 this now works.

```
Hibernate: insert into enrg (nm, ns, tmcr, entp) values (?, ?, ?, 'ws')
Hibernate: insert into ws (exdr, enid) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: If Hibernate doesn't support discriminators on JOINED strategy then I'm sure there are plenty of other JPA providers that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6912) and [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911) help you.

In the end only `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy requires a `discriminator` column, `JOINED` can be implemented without. The problem with Hibernate currently is that it causes inconsistent data when persisting sub entities in a `JOINED` inheritance mapped with `@DiscriminatorColumn`, even though the `JPA` spec recommends to persist discriminator values if a discriminator is used with `JOINED`.

Comment: The more I read about Hibernate, the less I like it. Honestly, it takes much less time to manually manage prepared statements than to read and resolve problems buried in a library implementation.

Comment: @jacekn yes correct, its `statement` and `perpared statement` only under Hibernate, but `Hibernate` does comes up with lot more, like session management, caching etc.

More you read and implement, More you will like.:P

Comment: @jacekn have a look [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911), also try using `DiscriminatorColumn` instead of `DiscriminatorValue `

Comment: The link only talks about the problem. At this point, it doesn't add anything to the resolution.

Comment: I have installed Tomee 1.7 and downloaded Hibernate 4.3.6. Looks like it made the difference 'cause I see an SQL statement that includes the entity type, now. However, code still fails downstream for some odd HsqlException.